# Flutter: How to restore ListView position?

Tags: flutter

When routing master `ListView` and its detail `ItemView` with `Navigator`, scroll position of the `ListView` was lost on back stack.

How to restore `ListView` scroll position?

Reusing `ListView` widget also lost position - also do not see reusing Widget in flutter example.

Sample code as request by Rainer,

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new MaterialApp(

  routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
    '/': (BuildContext context) => new MyListView(),
  },
  onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings s) {
    final List<String> paths = name.split('/');
    ...
    return new new ItemView(paths[1])
  }
}
```

In `MyListView`, when `ItemRow.onTab => Navigator.pushNamed(c, '/item/1')`.

In `ItemView` back button call `Navigator.pushNamed('/');`

Both Widget are stateful

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem. My ListView keeps state. Is your ListView wrapped in a Stateful or a StatelessWidget? Can you share some code?

Comment: May be `Navigator.pop()` restore previous widget state. Both widget are stateful.

Comment: I see. It should [saved scroll position](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ScrollController/keepScrollOffset.html). I must be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Here is some sample code.

[image: screenshot]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new MyHomePage(),
  ));
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new ListView(
          children: new List.generate(100, (int index) {
            return new ListTile(
              title: new Text('Item $index'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  new MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return new Scaffold(
                        body: new Center(
                          child: new RaisedButton(
                            child: new Text('Pop!'),
                            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Make sure you're using [`Navigator.pop()`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pop.html) instead of `Navigator.pushNamed('/');` to go back. If it doesn't work, please post more of your code or [file an issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new).

Comment: Why `Navigator.pushNamed('/');` does not work? `ListView` should restore offset if `new List.generate(100, (int index) {key: const ValueKey('100');}`.

Comment: Push adds a new empty route to the navigator stack. Pop restores previous routes

Comment: Just want added that to restore ListView position, the ListView must be re-used, so [Widget `Key`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Widget/key.html) of ListView and its parent key must not be changed during the transition period.